# Unable to convert Tensorflow from 1.0 to Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have tensorflow 1.0 version code and unable to convert tensorflow 2.0 using below syntax.
Could you please help me out ?

A)

```
lstm_cell =tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=hidden_unit)
#lstm_cell = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob)
```

Q -1) how to use drop out for the lstm_cell on Tf2.0?

B)

```
self._initial_state = lstm_cell.zero_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
```

Q-2 ) when I use above syntax,am getting an error `"LSTM cell does not have zero_state cell for TF2.0"`

How to initialize lSTM cell?

C) how to use tf.keras.layers.RNN cell for TF2.0

Answer (score 1):

Thank @AlexisBRENON !!! ..
Here is my code . Please let me know if I did any mistake .

```
lstm_cell =tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=hidden_unit)
    lstm_cell = tf.nn.RNNCellDropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=self.dropout_keep_prob)
    self._initial_state = lstm_cell.get_initial_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
    inputs = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1]) for input_ in tf.split(pooled_concat,num_or_size_splits=int(reduced),axis=1)]

    outputs, state_size =tf.keras.layers.RNN(lstm_cell, inputs, initial_state=self._initial_state, return_sequences=self.real_len)

    ==>>> Want to  Collect the appropriate last words into variable output (dimension = batch x embedding_size)
    output = outputs[0]
```

ERROR:-
    self._initial_state = lstm_cell.get_initial_state(self.batch_size, tf.float32)
ValueError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds. for 'strided_slice' (op: 'StridedSlice') with input shapes: [0], [1], [1], [1] and with computed input tensors: input[1] = <0>, input[2] = <1>, input[3] = <1>.

Comment: If the initial question is answered, I would recommend to open a _new_ question for your _new_ error.

Comment: By the way, you should provide a minimal reproducible example. What are the values of `hidden_unit`, `self.real_len`, etc.

Comment: Moreover, you are adding a `RNNCellDropoutWrapper` to a `LSTM` layer and not to a `LSTMCell` (I don't know the difference), are you sure of what you do? Finally, you should probably use an `Input` layer (with defined `input_shape`) to allow TF to track the shape of your LSTM layer.

Answer (score 0):

For the RNN dropout, the `DropoutWrapper` has been move to [`tf.nn.RNNCellDropoutWrapper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/RNNCellDropoutWrapper).

I suppose that [`tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell.get_initial_state`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTMCell#get_initial_state) is the new name of `zero_state`.

You should be more precise on what you want to do with RNNs. `tf.keras.layers.RNN` is a base class for recurrent layers and should not be used as is. Instead, you should use some sub-classes like [`SimpleRNN`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/SimpleRNN), [`GRU`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRU) or [`LSTM`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM), or make your own sub-class. Take a look at the tutorial on [recurrent neural network](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn).

Comment: outputs, state_size =tf.keras.layers.RNN(lstm_cell, inputs, initial_state=self._initial_state, return_sequences=self.real_len)


I want to Collect the appropriate last words into variable output (dimension = batch x embedding_size) using RNN return outpput cell 
output = outputs[0]